# Reactivating Corsa gamma features

Tags: corsa, horn

Hi all not sure if you've covered this yet....

A while ago my passenger side window wasn't working, so every time I tried to lock the car, it would honk twice....very annoying!
I didn't have money to repair the window right away so I took it to a mechanic and he disabled that "feature" so now when I locked it, it wouldn't honk.
I've since then repaired the window...but now I want to enable the "feature" again, but would like to learn how to do it, instead of taking it back to a mechanic.
Any help would be appreciated.
Corsa gamma 2006.

Comment: There are many ways to disable this feature.  You're best bet is to ask the mechanic how he disabled it and go from there.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Agree with Steve...we don't know what the mechanic did to disable it, so we wouldn't know what to do to re-enable it.